# elasticsearch and liferay dxp search

Tags: elasticsearch, liferay, liferay-dxp

I want to know how I get user information from liferay table in elasticsearch panel.Suppose I have created two users in liferay and  reindex user entity then i want to get those data.Is there any way to get those user from elasticsearch panel located localhost:9200.My elasticsearch running in embedded mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on my phone but I believe going into the search portlet's configuration and choosing to see results in document mode will give you what you're after.

Then search for the user and expand it's document view in the search results list.

Edit to add:

1. Click the options menu on the search portlet (kebab icon).
2. Click the *Configuration* option.
3. Click the *Other Settings* tab.
4. Choose *Display Results in Document Form*.
5. Search for a user.
6. Click *Details...* in the search results.

Edit again:

`http://localhost:9200/liferay-20116/_search?q=screenName:wmozart`
Gets you the document as well. My example is running ES on `localhost:9200`, the index name is `liferay-20116` (leave it out to search all indices), and my user's Screen Name is `wmozart`.

Comment: can u please brief me in detail?

Comment: Don't leave me hanging ;) Is one of those approaches what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi i have another question.i have created folder and upload image in it.how can i access it within elasticsearch?what is the url to access or is there a way to access it ?

Comment: Why do you need to keep accessing documents? Use either approach outlined above, substituting a field applicable to a docs and media folder for screenName. You can inspect all the indexed fields in the mapping, I just can't remember how off the top of my head.